# Average distance between a city's residents and bank branches

Tags: qgis, network

I am using QGIS. I got the banks layer from OpenStreetMap data. How can I use population density data to calculate the average distance between city's residents and bank branches in that city?

Comment: To answer this question, please provide examples of concrete data. Specifically, what format is the population density data in? Is it raster? points? Are there values inside polygons? These questions do not give any answers.

Comment: I don't have population density data for the moment, where can I find this type o Data for My country: Morocco? and what are the different types of population density data I can use?

Comment: Usually you have to process this data yourself. Most countries provide regional population data, so you can calculate the population density by taking polygons for the boundaries of the region. However, it is entirely up to you how much detail you want to scale for the desired analysis.

Comment: i m planning to start with one region, but i dont know how population data by region can be used for this, because after all its a an average  (number of people divided by the surface of the region) how can i use it to calculate  the average distance between the region's residents and bank branches in that region?